# Split Dataframe to multiple Dataframes by sub columns

Tags: python, pandas

I could not find an elegant way to split this table :

```
Open              Close                High 
 stock1 stock2     stock1 stock2        stock1 stock2
  ..     ..         ..      ..           ..     ..
```

Where stocks are sub columns,
into multiple tables each for a stock, so first table is

**df_stock1**

```
   Open Close High
```

so a table/dataframe for each stock ( could be > 2 ) then return an array of those `dataframes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. Here's a fictiv dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (6, 6)),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Open', 'Close', 'High'],
                                                      ['Stock1', 'Stock2']]))
```

which prints:

```
Open         Close          High       
  Stock1 Stock2 Stock1 Stock2 Stock1 Stock2
0      3      3      7      2      4      7
1      2      1      2      1      1      4
2      5      1      1      5      2      8
3      4      3      5      8      3      5
4      9      1      8      4      5      7
5      2      6      7      3      2      9
```

Then to split your multi-index df, do the following, using groupby and DataFrame.xs:

```
Split = {idx: df_sub.xs(idx, level=1, axis=1) for idx,df_sub in df.groupby(level=1, axis=1)}
print(Split['Stock1'])
```

where `df_sub` refers to the first-level of the multiindex df. This givess:

```
 Open  Close  High
0     3      7     4
1     2      2     1
2     5      1     2
3     4      5     3
4     9      8     5
5     2      7     2
```

and

```
Split2 = {idx: df_sub.xs(idx, level=1, axis=1) for idx,df_sub in df.groupby(level=1, axis=1)}
print(Split2['Stock2'])
```

prints:

```
 Open  Close  High
0     3      2     7
1     1      1     4
2     1      5     8
3     3      8     5
4     1      4     7
5     6      3     9
```

**EDIT** Other levels

Similarily, if you want all the Open stocks, you can do this:

```
Split_open = {idx: df_sub.xs(idx, level=0, axis=1) for idx,df_sub in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)}
print(Split_open['Open'])
```

which returns:

```
   Stock1  Stock2
0       3       3
1       2       1
2       5       1
3       4       3
4       9       1
5       2       6
```

Comment: If it is the answer you were lookig for, do mark it as the accepted answer so it disappears from the list of unanswered questions. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. This was a really good question, and well formulated! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks. Where can i read more about what you did ? what's the name of the functions you used?

Comment: Well actually i could not find any reference to what you did, they only thing i can read about is xs, but no idea what gp is, and what's happening there, if you could add that.

Comment: I will later on, after my meetings :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231701/discussion-between-serge-de-gosson-de-varennes-and-shulas).

Comment: I see the confusion you experienced (I refered to gp right after group by....which was not really pedagogical. Sorry about that. I changed gp to df_sub and added an explanation. There is no procedure called gp and I understand why you were confused. My bad!