# Split the groups formed by df.groupby() into multiple dataframes with those grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with columns such as `transmission`, `drivetrain` and `fuel_type` and all these three are categorical. Now if I run the code:

```
df.groupby(['Transmission','dt','Fuel_Type'])['PRICE'].mean()
```

it gives me multiple groups and their mean prices. what I want is suppose this groupby gives me output like this (5 groups):

```
Transmission    dt              Fuel_Type           PRICE       
Automatic      All-Wheel Drive  Diesel              4.851505e+04    
                                Flex Fuel Vehicle   8.017633e+04    

               Four-Wheel Drive Biodiesel           6.683117e+04    
                                Diesel              5.750627e+04
CVT            All-Wheel Drive  Gasoline            2.718781e+04
```

So now I want 5 new dataframes with their respective `transmission`, `drivetrain` and `fuel_type` values and other entries and columns.

Comment: Hi! Can you share a sample of the data? Might be helpful. Also, could this be the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299358/split-dataframe-to-multiple-dataframes-by-sub-columns/67299621?noredirect=1#comment118959039_67299621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following thing. Asssume your dataframe looks like this:

```
Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type     PRICE
0     Automatic   All-Wheel Drive    Diesel    434344
1        Manual  Four-Wheel Drive    Diesel    323232
2           CVT   All-Wheel Drive    Diesel      5355
3     Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive    Diesel  53534534
4        Manual  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline   4424422
5           CVT   All-Wheel Drive  Gasoline    242442
6     Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline     42424
7        Manual  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline     57757
8           CVT  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline      4244
9     Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex     78997
10       Manual   All-Wheel Drive      Flex      7989
11          CVT  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex     46456
12    Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex      4646
13       Manual   All-Wheel Drive      Flex      4646
14          CVT  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex    487979
```

Now, you need to compute the mean by group:

```
df.groupby(['Transmission', 'drivetrain', 'Fuel_type'])['PRICE'].mean()
```

which prints:

```
Transmission  drivetrain        Fuel_type
Automatic     All-Wheel Drive   Diesel         434344.0
              Four-Wheel Drive  Diesel       53534534.0
                                Flex            41821.5
                                Gasoline        42424.0
CVT           All-Wheel Drive   Diesel           5355.0
                                Gasoline       242442.0
              Four-Wheel Drive  Flex           267217.5
                                Gasoline         4244.0
Manual        All-Wheel Drive   Flex             6317.5
              Four-Wheel Drive  Diesel         323232.0
                                Gasoline      2241089.5
Name: PRICE, dtype: float64
```

Now, to bee able to create separate dataframes for each group:

```
(Automatic, Four-Wheel Drive, Diesel, Mean)
((Automatic, All-Wheel Drive, Diesel, Mean)
......
```

You can turn each combination to elements in a dictionary:

```
Groups = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['Transmission','drivetrain','Fuel_type'])))
Groups
```

Which gives:

```
{('Automatic',
  'All-Wheel Drive',
  'Diesel'):   Transmission       drivetrain Fuel_type   PRICE
 0    Automatic  All-Wheel Drive    Diesel  434344,
 ('Automatic',
  'Four-Wheel Drive',
  'Diesel'):   Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type     PRICE
 3    Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive    Diesel  53534534,
 ('Automatic',
  'Four-Wheel Drive',
  'Flex'):    Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type  PRICE
 9     Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex  78997
 12    Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex   4646,
 ('Automatic',
  'Four-Wheel Drive',
  'Gasoline'):   Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type  PRICE
 6    Automatic  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline  42424,
 ('CVT',
  'All-Wheel Drive',
  'Diesel'):   Transmission       drivetrain Fuel_type  PRICE
 2          CVT  All-Wheel Drive    Diesel   5355,
 ('CVT',
  'All-Wheel Drive',
  'Gasoline'):   Transmission       drivetrain Fuel_type   PRICE
 5          CVT  All-Wheel Drive  Gasoline  242442,
 ('CVT',
  'Four-Wheel Drive',
  'Flex'):    Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type   PRICE
 11          CVT  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex   46456
 14          CVT  Four-Wheel Drive      Flex  487979,
 ('CVT',
  'Four-Wheel Drive',
  'Gasoline'):   Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type  PRICE
 8          CVT  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline   4244,
 ('Manual',
  'All-Wheel Drive',
  'Flex'):    Transmission       drivetrain Fuel_type  PRICE
 10       Manual  All-Wheel Drive      Flex   7989
 13       Manual  All-Wheel Drive      Flex   4646,
 ('Manual',
  'Four-Wheel Drive',
  'Diesel'):   Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type   PRICE
 1       Manual  Four-Wheel Drive    Diesel  323232,
 ('Manual',
  'Four-Wheel Drive',
  'Gasoline'):   Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type    PRICE
 4       Manual  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline  4424422
 7       Manual  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline    57757}
```

From there, you can extract any combination you want, for instance:

```
df_aut_drive_fuel = Groups['Automatic','All-Wheel Drive', 'Diesel']
```

which gives:

```
Transmission       drivetrain Fuel_type   PRICE
0    Automatic  All-Wheel Drive    Diesel  434344
```

or

```
df_man_drive_fuel =Groups['Manual','Four-Wheel Drive', 'Gasoline']
```

which returns:

```
Transmission        drivetrain Fuel_type    PRICE
4       Manual  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline  4424422
7       Manual  Four-Wheel Drive  Gasoline    57757
```

Comment: Yes brother, it worked quickly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped!